# Would a vibrating metallic and charged surface emit electrons?

Tags: electrons, vibrations, metals

Consider a metallic object under an intense electric field so its electrically charged in its surface. If the object is set to vibrate could it emit electrons? Maybe if the frequency is high enough? Or is it more about the amplitude of oscillations?

This effect would be similar to thermionic emission where the electron can escape due to temperature. I have been trying to find a similar mechanism for vibrations but I do not know what keywords to use to find anything like it. What would be the adequate range of frequency to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

To translate what you're talking about to technical physics language, you're describing phonon-assisted field emission of elections. In other words, apply an electric field and high frequency vibrations allow for electrons to jump out of the material.

The characteristic frequencies here are the resonant frequencies of the atomic lattice structure itself (i.e. phonons), which are typically 1-50 THz, and are well above what you could get with ordinary audio transducers. Typically, one has to heat up the material to excite such vibrations or come up with another clever way to generate these phonons because they are in a unique frequency range above RF but below optical light.

Here is one paper you can read on this topic
"[Phonon-Assisted Electron Emission from Individual Carbon Nanotubes](https://doi.org/10.1021/nl103861p)" by Wei et al.

Comment: Are these estimations for any material? I see that the source talks mostly about semiconductors.

Comment: The range of vibrational frequencies is largely dictated but the mass of the atoms, more so than whether the material is a metal or not. That said, you can get rather slow vibrations in heavy materials, but the higher frequency ones would play bigger roles in electron emission anyways